# Move recently added desktop files to a directory

Tags: vbscript, desktop, transfer

I'm trying to create a batch file script which helps me transferring the new files from desktop to a directory whenever I'm accesing it. I'm working with graphics and I create/save a lot of new elements on the desktop.

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, VBS is probably not the best way (just use a .bat or PowerShell or Robocopy). In your second example, you loop over a collection of `File` objects, and then you do not do anything with that `File` object. What are you expecting to happen there?

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I wanted to move all objects from desktop (all types of objects) to a folder.